# Application working fine in simulator but not on iPad

Tags: ipad, memory-management, uiview, opengl-es

I am developing a game using OpenGL ES and its menu using many images and Opengl view .
My application is working fine in simulator but crashes in ipad.
And its not crashing at a specific point, my application don't have any leaks but getting memory warnings of level 1 and level 2 .
Any suggestions will be of great help.

I checked my code using instruments and my application crashes while loading the texture images in the memory, then i divide the loading part , now my application works fine , but using around 50 MB of memory, and getting memory warning level 1 only, how much memory can i use in ipad for proper functioning of the application?

Comment: I suggest a new keyboard, your exclamation mark must be sticking

Comment: With "many images", your application doesn't need to have leaks to put memory pressure on the system.  When you run the Memory Monitor instrument against your application, what does its memory usage look like at the point it crashes?

Comment: i got my problem, actually while loading texture data at a single frame cause the problem. now i have to load data in more than one frame.

Comment: The crash report / crash message would be very helpful.